# ARM Cortex M4 - C Programming and Memory Access Optimization

Tags: c, arm, gpio, cortex-m

The following three lines of code are optimized ways to modify bits with 1 MOV instruction instead of using a less interrupt safe *read-modify-write* idiom. They are identical to each other, and set the LED_RED bit in the GPIO Port's Data Register:

1. `*((volatile unsigned long*)(0x40025000 + (LED_RED << 2))) = LED_RED;`
2. `*(GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED) = LED_RED;`
3. `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R[LED_RED] = LED_RED;`

`LED_RED` is simply `(volatile unsigned long) 0x02`. In the memory map of this microcontroller, the first 2 LSBs of this register (and others) are unused, so the left shift in the first example makes sense.

The definition for GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R is:

`#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R  ((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025000)`

**My question is:** How come I do not need to left shift twice when using pointer arithmetic or array indexing (2nd method and 3rd method, respectively)? I'm having a hard time understanding. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as "less interrupt safe" code - there is code that is interrupt safe, and code that is not interrupt safe.  And don't assume that a single line of C means a single write - make sure you are writing to a "set" or "clear" register in the GPIO, and then it will be safe.

Comment: Using the same LED_RED value as part of the address, and as the value you are writing, is almost certainly wrong.  But without knowing details of the microcontroller and the value LED_RED, it is impossible to know.  It might work as you expect by luck, but not by design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember how C pointer arithmetic works: adding an offset to a pointer operates in units of the type pointed to.  Since `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R` has type `unisgned long *`, and `sizeof(unsigned long) == 4`, then `GPIO_PORTF_DATA_BITS_R + LED_RED` effectively adds `2 * 4` = 8 bytes.

Note that (1) does arithmetic on `0x40025000`, which is an integer, not a pointer, so we need to add 8 to get the same result.  Left shift by 2 is the same as multiplication by 4, so `LED_RED << 2` again equals 8.

(3) is exactly equivalent to (2) by definition of the `[]` operator.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, it's perfectly clear now. It seems I made it this far without intuitively understanding the connections between pointer arithmetic and array indexing, and how types come into play. Thanks for making this one click